# Execute code only after user clicks 'update' button for CPT being edited

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, hooks

In my plugin, my custom post type posts might be updated either by a user clicking 'update' on the editor page, or programmatically.  I need to execute a settings validation routine **only** when the update was done by a human.  This is what I came up with but I was wondering if there is a better way?

In class constructor:

```
add_action( 'save_post_my-CPT, array( &$this, 'after_save_cpt' ) );
```

Callback function:

```
/* code to run after the user has updated/saved a CPT */
public function after_save_cpt( ) {
    if ( function_exists( 'get_current_screen' ) )                                          
        $cur_screen = get_current_screen()->parent_file;                                    
    else
        $cur_screen = '';                           
    if ( 'my-settings-screen' != $cur_screen ) {                                                        
        remove_action( 'save_post_my-CPT, array( &$this, 'after_save_cpt' ) );      
        do_action( 'validate_all_settings' );  
    }
}
```

It seems to work ok and it basically says that if they are not on the settings page for the plugin (where the 'programmatic' post update might happen), to fire the action 'validate_all_settings', which is caught by function hook in another class.

I don't like this for two reasons (a) if that 'remove_action' doesn't happen for whatever reason, it'll infinite-loop and exhaust stack memory, and (b) it still runs once even if they are not on the post editor page.

I was hoping for something like "fire this code ONLY if the user is on a page sourced from **edit.php**".  I could not figure out a way to do that.

Comment: I'm a little confused. I don't think that setting/option pages land on `edit.php` but their own slug or slug plus query vars. How does it save it programmatically? Are you referring to auto-saving by chance?

Comment: Right - I only want to execute the action 'validate_all_settings' if the CPT had been updated via 'update' button from edit.php.  It just so happens that one of the things my setting/option page code does is to create several posts of CPT -- in that case the 'save_post_my-CPT' hook will fire - and the code above does ignore that.  So what I have here works fine.  I was just hoping for a more elegant solution.